# Ordenar dicionário

Tags: python, classificação, dicionário

Estou tentando ordenar esse dicionário por ordem crescente de notas, eu tentei usar a essa função, mas ela elimina as notas repetidas, o que eu devo fazer?

```
def Ordena_dic_notas(dic):
    dic_ord=dict()
    dic_invertido=dict()
    notas=[]
    nomes=[]
    for i in dic.keys():
        dic_invertido[dic[i]]=i
        nomes.append(i)
        notas.append(dic[i])
    notas.sort()
    for i in notas:
        nome=dic_invertido[i]
        dic_ord[nome]=i
    return dic_ord 

dic_de_notas={'Alexandre': 5.2, 'Alice': 6.7, 'Amanda': 7.3, 'Ana': 8.7,
              'Arthur': 9.2, 'Bernardo': 9.4, 'Brenda': 8.5, 'Bruno': 3.2,
              'Carlos': 4.1, 'Daniel': 6.8, 'Denilson': 9.7, 'Évelyn': 9.1,
              'Édson': 4.1, 'Gabriel': 10.0, 'Giovana': 9.3, 'Goberjelson': 0.2,
              'Helena': 7.2, 'Henrique': 8.5, 'Jorge': 6.8, 'Jorgel': 8.9,
              'Júlia': 5.6, 'Júlio': 9.0, 'Karen': 7.0, 'Kevin': 8.0,
              'Leonardo': 8.5, 'Luis': 5.8, 'Luiza': 4.9, 'Maria': 4.1,
              'Marcelo': 7.5, 'Matheus': 9.2, 'Neymar': 5.8, 'Omar': 9.9,
              'Paulo': 6.3, 'Pauderley': 8.7, 'Pauloney': 7.2,
              'Pirugorjelson': 1.0, 'Pirujelson': 1.5, 'Rafael': 7.0,
              'Tatiana': 9.4, 'Thiago': 8.6, 'Uberley': 2.4,
              'Valdinélison': 0.9, 'Vitória': 2.3, 'Wagner': 8.9,
              'Yasmin': 9.6, 'Yuri': 8.3}
```

Comment: Lembrando que os dicionário em Python só garante ordenação por ordem de inserção da versão 3.7 em diante (Ver [nota na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)). Se sua versão não for compatível seria melhor usar um [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código possui coisas desnecessárias e esbarra numa impossibilidade:

- `dic_invertido=dict()` não há razão de existir pois ele não faz o que quer faça. Uma das características de um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) é que as chaves sejam únicas ou seja, ao tentar criar um dicionário onde as notas sejam as chaves e nomes os valores ocorre que as notas duplicadas serão sobrescritas pela última entrada gerando o comportamento que descreveu na pergunta.
- As listas  `nomes=[]` e `notas=[]` também possuem motivo para existirem pois tipo nativo [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) oferece os métodos [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), que retorna uma iterável das chaves do dicionário, e [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), que retorna uma iterável dos valores do dicionário.

Um dos caminhos para classificar o dicionário `dic_de_notas` segundo os valores das notas é aplicar a função nativa [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sorted), que retorna uma lista classificada a partir de um iterável, aos itens dum dicionário obtidos pelo método [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), que retorna um iterável dos itens do dicionário em tuplas `(chave, valor)`.
A função `sorted()` possui um argumento `key` que é utilizado para extrair uma chave de comparação de cada elemento do iterável. Nesse caso use uma função `lambda t:t[1]` para indicar que da tupla `(chave, valor)` o valor é o parâmetro de comparação.

```
def Ordena_dic_notas(d):
  return dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t:t[1]))

dic_de_notas={
  'Alexandre': 5.2, 'Alice': 6.7, 'Amanda': 7.3, 'Ana': 8.7,
  'Arthur': 9.2, 'Bernardo': 9.4, 'Brenda': 8.5, 'Bruno': 3.2,
  'Carlos': 4.1, 'Daniel': 6.8, 'Denilson': 9.7, 'Évelyn': 9.1,
  'Édson': 4.1, 'Gabriel': 10.0, 'Giovana': 9.3, 'Goberjelson': 0.2,
  'Helena': 7.2, 'Henrique': 8.5, 'Jorge': 6.8, 'Jorgel': 8.9,
  'Júlia': 5.6, 'Júlio': 9.0, 'Karen': 7.0, 'Kevin': 8.0,
  'Leonardo': 8.5, 'Luis': 5.8, 'Luiza': 4.9, 'Maria': 4.1,
  'Marcelo': 7.5, 'Matheus': 9.2, 'Neymar': 5.8, 'Omar': 9.9,
  'Paulo': 6.3, 'Pauderley': 8.7, 'Pauloney': 7.2,
  'Pirugorjelson': 1.0, 'Pirujelson': 1.5, 'Rafael': 7.0,
  'Tatiana': 9.4, 'Thiago': 8.6, 'Uberley': 2.4,
  'Valdinélison': 0.9, 'Vitória': 2.3, 'Wagner': 8.9,
  'Yasmin': 9.6, 'Yuri': 8.3
}

print(Ordena_dic_notas(dic_de_notas))
```

Que retorna:

```
{
 'Goberjelson': 0.2, 'Valdinélison': 0.9, 'Pirugorjelson': 1.0, 'Pirujelson': 1.5, 
 'Vitória': 2.3, 'Uberley': 2.4, 'Bruno': 3.2, 'Carlos': 4.1, 'Édson': 4.1, 'Maria': 4.1, 
 'Luiza': 4.9, 'Alexandre': 5.2, 'Júlia': 5.6, 'Luis': 5.8, 'Neymar': 5.8, 'Paulo': 6.3, 
 'Alice': 6.7, 'Daniel': 6.8, 'Jorge': 6.8, 'Karen': 7.0, 'Rafael': 7.0, 'Helena': 7.2, 
 'Pauloney': 7.2, 'Amanda': 7.3, 'Marcelo': 7.5, 'Kevin': 8.0, 'Yuri': 8.3, 'Brenda': 8.5,
 'Henrique': 8.5, 'Leonardo': 8.5, 'Thiago': 8.6, 'Ana': 8.7, 'Pauderley': 8.7, 'Jorgel': 8.9, 
 'Wagner': 8.9, 'Júlio': 9.0, 'Évelyn': 9.1, 'Arthur': 9.2, 'Matheus': 9.2, 'Giovana': 9.3, 
 'Bernardo': 9.4, 'Tatiana': 9.4, 'Yasmin': 9.6, 'Denilson': 9.7, 'Omar': 9.9,
 'Gabriel': 10.0
}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/DicClassificado1)</sup>